# Frontend & Solidity union skills learning

Tags: solidity, javascript, frontend

if I'm going to learn solidity, but I don't know for sure whether I want to be a blockchain developer or a front-end developer, what skills are in demand in that area, so that learning solidity will improve my skills in the front as well

Comment: It is a subjective question, without a "correct" answer. Unfortunately they are out of scope for a technical forum like this site.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, dedicating extensive time to learning Solidity might not significantly enhance your prospects in front-end development. It's often more beneficial to focus on mastering JavaScript and popular front-end frameworks like Next.js or React.js.

However, for web3 developers, the integration of smart contracts into the frontend is essential. Front-end engineers need to establish connections with smart contracts, executing and retrieving data from their functions. While an in-depth knowledge of Solidity may not be needed for frontend careers, having a foundational understanding is crucial for establishing this connection. A basic grasp of Solidity enables developers to read functions and execute them, bridging the gap between frontend and smart contract interactions.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need very much the knowledge of solidity in both blockchain developement and front end development

Answer (score 0):

> learning solidity will improve my skills in the front as well

Solidity is unlikely to improve your frontend development skills and any experience in Solidity poorly translates to other programming environments. Solidity is a niche technology in a niche industry. For your career prospects it is better to become good (productive) in frontend first, and then look Solidity later when you have at least few years of working experience, hireable and generally better understanding about programming fundamentals.